# Turn off Worksheet_Change when another function is working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem, i want to use function like this:

```
Private Sub Clear_WSK1(arrayValWSKrow1 As Variant)
    Dim r As Integer

    For r = 0 To 30
        Workbooks("1_W.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(4, r + 4).Value = arrayValWSKrow1(r)
    Next r
End Sub
```

But in the same sheet I got: `Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
When I call `Clear_WSK1` the function is interrupted because the first iteration of For loop changes value of the cell and it automatically calls `Worksheet_Change` function. Is there a way to turn off `Worksheet_Change` function while `Clear_WSK1` is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a statement `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top of the routine to disable the events.

Don't forget to set it back to `True` after your work is done - and maybe add an error handler to do so even if an error occurs.